# Selenium gecko browser can't find element

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver

Not really sure why, but it seems to have an error finding the element in Gecko Browser.  Works perfectly In Chrome. Tried different variations as well.  So the job only seems to go 50%  then stops

here it is: 
       package src;

```
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;

public class ha {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

    // declaration and instantiation of objects/variables
    WebDriver driver ;
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver","C:\\Users\\Bain1\\eclipse-workspace\\New Project\\geckodriver.exe");
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();

    //Create explicit wait.
    WebDriverWait myWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);

    String baseUrl = "http://newtours.demoaut.com/";
    driver.get(baseUrl);

    //wait until text box load.
    myWait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.name("userName")));

    // Enter value into textbox
    driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys ("tutorial");

    // Delete value from textbox
    driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).clear();

    // Access Links
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Register here")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.partialLinkText("SIGN-ON")).click();

    // Enter value into textbox and SUBMIT
    driver.findElement(By.name("userName")).sendKeys ("tutorial");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).sendKeys ("tutorial");
    driver.findElement(By.name("password")).submit();

    // Select Radio Button
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("input[value=Business]")).click();

    //Select CheckBox
    String baseURL = "http://demo.guru99.com/sele...";
    driver.get(baseURL);

    //Create an Explicit wait.
    WebDriverWait myWait2 = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
    myWait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("persist_box")));

    WebElement chkFBPersist = driver.findElement(By.id("persist_box"));
    for (int i=0; i<2; i++) {
        chkFBPersist.click (); 
        System.out.println(chkFBPersist.isSelected());
    }

    driver.quit();
    System.exit(0);
}
}
```

a

```
1500950108846   geckodriver INFO    geckodriver 0.18.0
1500950108853   geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:46140
1500950109519   geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser C:\Program Files (x86)\Mozilla Firefox\firefox.exe with args ["-marionette"]
1500950111367   Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 56333
Jul 25, 2017 12:35:11 PM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake createSession
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: Unable to locate element: Register here
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: 'unknown', time: 'unknown'
System info: host: 'DESKTOP-OOA5BSF', ip: '101.011.01.111', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_141'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\Bain1\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.BQUc6ozUnkyX, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0.0, pageLoad=300000.0, script=30000.0}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0.0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=54.0.1, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=15212.0, browserName=firefox, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: b78462ce-e9bf-4143-a4a4-5c8b5a99f863
*** Element info: {Using=link text, value=Register here}
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:150)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:115)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:45)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:164)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:637)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:410)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementByLinkText(RemoteWebDriver.java:461)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ByLinkText.findElement(By.java:246)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:402)
    at src.ha.main(ha.java:35)
```

Comment: Can you add some implicit wait and try again?

Comment: @santhoshkumar I can try but it appears as if gecko does not acknowledge this element exists at all.  <a href="mercuryregister.php?osCsid=9991bbed9e0562e284b47c61408e24fb">Register 
                    here</a>  http://newtours.demoaut.com/

Comment: It is REGISTER of Register here?

Comment: @santhoshkumar I'm after register here - below the sign up button down the page

Comment: @santhoshkumar https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/322 - Supposedly clicks do not work.  This is a known bug.  I will investigate using Gecko in a different version of Selenium.  What a nightmare....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the Answer to your Question:

To click on `Register here` link within the URL `http://newtours.demoaut.com/` you can use the following line of code:

```
// Click on "Register here"
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'mercuryregister.php?')][contains(text(),'Register')]")).click();
```

Let me know if this Answers your Question.

Comment: Cheers.  Gecko Firefox Selectors tend to be a lot more finicky then Chrome.  But this worked for me.  Thought it was a bug as there's quite a few people complaining about Gecko not working for them.  https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/322

Comment: Might look up a few guides on dynamic selectors and test which works best with Gecko

Comment: Yup @BarryLance Let us know if you need any further help. Upvote the Answer if it was useful to you. Thanks